# Python make_zipfile script fail to complete

Tags: python, zip, pyscripter

HELP! - the zip was never complete as it only zipped 2GB out of 6GB which is the original file size.

```
def make_zipfile(output_filename, source_dir):
    relroot = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(source_dir, ".."))
    with zipfile.ZipFile(output_filename, "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source_dir):
            # add directory (needed for empty dirs)
            zip.write(root, os.path.relpath(root, relroot))
            for file in files:
                filename = os.path.join(root, file)
                if os.path.isfile(filename): # regular files only
                    arcname = os.path.join(os.path.relpath(root, relroot), file)
                    zip.write(filename, arcname)
```

Comment: What filesystem?  What OS?  Did you try opening the resulting zip file?

Comment: have you tried [`shutil.make_archive()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#archiving-operations)?

Comment: OS - Window Server 2008. Yes, I tried to opened the resulting zip file and it is just 2GB where should be the same size as the original file.